# TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable scipy minimize

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I am trying to minimize the function using the constrains and bounds as below, however after running it I am getting error:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable.
```

Can you tell me how to avoid it?

I am also not sure if I am doing well with using the main
function as a integrate.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy as sp
from scipy.integrate import quad
import math


# obj funtion
def f(x):
    l = sp.Symbol('l')
    Ep = 45000
    Gc = 1
    F = 1080
    ep = x[0]
    ec = x[1]
    return (((F ** 2 * (l - x)) / (Ep * ec * l * (ec + ep) ** 2)) + (F ** 2) / (2 * (ec + 2 * ec) * Gc * l)) / 100


mainf = quad(f, 0, 1800)


# constrain 1 - mass

def constrain1(x):
    pc = 4.5 * 10 ** (-5)
    pp = 2.1 * 10 ** (-3)
    V = 3.1 * 10 ** 7
    ep = x[0]
    ec = x[1]
    return ((((pp * V * ((2 * ep + ec) / 50) * ep) / (ec + 2 * ep)) + (
            (pc * V * ((2 * ep + ec) / 50) * ec) / (ec + 2 * ep))) / 1000) - 4.5


def constrain2(x):
    ep = x[0]
    ec = x[1]
    return (3.13107 * 10 ** 3) * ep * np.sqrt(ep / ec) - 1080


# initial guesses
x_init = [2, 50]

# bounds

b1 = (0, 3)
b2 = (30, 70)
bnds = (b1, b2)
con1 = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constrain1}
con2 = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constrain2}
cons = [con1, con2]

sol = minimize(mainf,x0=x_init,method='SLSQP',bounds=bnds,constraints=cons)
```

Comment: You have to identify which variable is being subscripted, and why it's a float (a scalar) instead of an array (or list).  We can't guess that from your code (unless it's copy-n-paste runable).

Comment: Include the *complete* error message (i.e. the complete traceback) in the question.  There is useful information in there.

Comment: It's probably the `x[0]` and `x[1]` in your integrand. I'm not sure what you're trying to do there but it's written as a 1-D function. That is, `x` is just a scalar value (the point at which the integral is being evaluated).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and seem to have found the solution.

First the meaning of the error:
As [explained here](https://researchdatapod.com/python-typeerror-float-object-is-not-subscriptable/), a subscriptable item is a container/collection holding several items. [These can be of type `dict`,  `list`, `set`, or `tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html). For me, and probably for you too, I was trying to access the second item `x[1]` of a `float`, which is not possible.

To solve the error in general (my problem):
Make sure your input value is actually a subscriptable item as described above.

For your specific error:
As I understand from the documentation, the function [scipy.integrate.quad(fun, a, b)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html) integrates the function `fun` between `floats` `a` and `b`. In other words, it finds the area under the function between these variables. Therefore I assume it inputs first `a`, then `b` and substracts the resulting answers. However, the objective function `f()` you are using needs a subscriptable item and therefore return a `TypeError`.

To fix it, make your obj function `f()` work with just one variable, or find a function that can input a subscriptable item.

Hope this helps.